# Is it possible to move product category description alignment in drupal

Tags: 7

Can any one suggest me to move Product description from top to bottom in drupal product category page.

Example Like :

1. First all product Image.
2. And Bottom content are shown.

Answer (score 1):

This can be also done through the admin dashboard. Follow the below steps:

1. Go to admin/structure/types.
2. Select your content/Product type and manage Display according to your requirement.

Comment: can you provide me communication id for understand in brief..How to do in back-end side.

Comment: Follow the steps I mentioned above. Back-end side means you want to customize the product type using `tpl.php` files?

Comment: [Drupal customizing content types](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.tpl.php/7). Follow this link for the detailed explanation for customizing `node.tpl.php` files.

Answer (score 0):

create `node--product.tpl.php` to theme the product category page.

Comment: can you provide me communication id for understand in brief.

Comment: Sorry i'm quite busy these days my id is rachit045@gmail.com